# Make a plane to display material from both sides

Tags: normals, unity, materials

I know there is a setting in Cry Engine, which allows you to be able to read materials of the plane from both sides, so I am wondering if there is such a setting in **Unity5**.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your shader source file in order to add "Cull Off" inside, more info [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/double-sided-material.21778/)

If you are not writing your own shaders (and so use default provided Unity shaders) then you can look at proposed solutions [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/standard-shader-2-sided.304812/)